# Django template and splitting the variable list

Tags: django, django-templates

In my django view, I pass a list that contains several items.

My html design is like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <div>1st item</div>
   <div>2nd item</div>
</li> 
 <li>
   <div>3th item</div>
   <div>4th item</div>
 </li> 
 <li>
   <div>5th item</div>
   <div>6th item</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

You see the pattern, every two items, I need to split them and put into a new `<li></li>`. How can I loop and divide these variables by every two using `{% for item in my_list %}`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this which isn't particularly elegant and isn't tested in any way!

```
{% if list_of_items %}
<ul>
<li>
  {% for item in list_of_items %}
  <div>{{ item }}</div>
  {% cycle '' '</li><li>' %}
  {% endfor %}
</li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

You could re-arrange the list in your view first to make it a list of lists, or alternatively you could write your own batch filter.

As far as I know there isn't a really easy django template way of doing what you want - Django templates are deliberately restrictive to encourage you to write python code instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the items have some property that groups them naturally into pairs, you can use `regroup`:

```
{% if list_of_items %}
    <ul>
    {% regroup list_of_items by property as item_chunks %}
    {% for chunk in item_chunks %}
        <li>
        {% for item in chunk.list %}
        {{ item }}
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

It's a couple more lines than Nick's solution, but if those elements do have a property that joins them naturally, I would say that this is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to enumerate your total list of 6 elements in batches of size 2 which gives you 3 batches and then loop through each batch.

To do this, you can add a custom batch filter in your templatetags directory. Here is the documentation for adding custom tag/filter.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Your custom filter can be something like this.

```
@register.filter

def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]
```

In your html

```
     {% for batch in yourlist|batch:2%}
        <li>
          {% for element in batch %}
              <div>{{element}}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer for Django 3.1

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-md-auto">
           <h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
        </div>

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"6" %}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```